# Rails covert id to value display in textbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm really new to rails and I'm trying to feel my way along. I know this is a very common scenario. I have a view where I'm displaying a dropdown of states. When the user saves the record, the state ID is stored in the database. The problem is I can't figure out how to use the ID to show the state.

Right now this is what my "show.html.erb" has

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: { class: "form-horizontal form-label-left" } do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', readonly:'readonly' %>
...
```

which of course only displays the state ID. Do I need to do the lookup in my model and display that...?

I know this is a super common scenario.

EDIT
Here is the dropdown that saves the id

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: { class: "form-horizontal form-label-left" } do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :state, nil, class: 'control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12' %>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <%= f.select :state, options_for_select(State.all.collect {|c| [ c.abbreviation, c.id ] }), class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is the controller

```
  def show
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the part of the code where the status ID is populated? the code you shared is for the `customer.name` only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are storing state `id` in database ? If you want to select state using state's abbreviation and want to display state's abbreviation then just store state's abbreviation in database.

Use `<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(State.all.collect {|c| [ c.abbreviation, c.abbreviation ] }), class: 'form-control' %>`

Or maybe you have relation between State and Customer model and you want to map customer record to state record, then in this case you will have to load state abbreviation from database

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @state = State.find(@customer.state).abbreviation
end
```

and then display state in your form

```
<%= text_field_tag @state, class: 'form-control', readonly:'readonly' %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Anil Maurya, when I use `<%= text_field @state, class: 'form-control', readonly:'readonly' %>` I get an error `undefined method` error. Any idea why?

Comment: use <%= text_field_tag @state, class: 'form-control', readonly:'readonly' %>

Answer (score 0):

> I'm really new to rails and I'm trying to feel my way along.

Welcome to the family!

--

Okay so you need to look at [`ActiveRecord` associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) - this will be the solution you need:

```
#app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  #columns id | state_id | name | etc | created_at | updated_at
  belongs_to :state, -> { pluck(:name) }
end

#app/models/state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :customers
end
```

This is a standard `has_many/belongs_to` association:

[image]

---

> I can't figure out how to use the ID to show the state

This is where the magic happens - you need to read up on [`foreign_keys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) - these are referential IDs which allow ActiveRecord to pull the associative data from the other model.

In simple terms, it means that if you set up your associations correctly in your model, you'll be able to call the following:

```
@customer = Customer.find params[:id]
@customer.state #-> "Colorado"
```

--

With regards your `form`, here's what you need to do (I'm guessing you're *editing* a customer, not creating):

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
   end
   def update
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
      @customer.update customer_params
   end

   private

   def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :state)
   end
end

#app/views/customers/edit.html.erb (HTML removed for convenience)
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :state, State.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

This will save the appropriate `state` attribute in your `Customer` model, allowing ActiveRecord to call it whenever you need to invoke it.